# Why does this keep giving errors?

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to code some stuff for a game but I keep getting error messages on 8 lines that keep saying "Expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '*attribute*' before "insert what it's talking about here""

Its annoying and I can't figure out why. Here is the code:

```
class Vec2 **"error here before Vec2"**
{
public:

float X, Y;

Vec2() {}
Vec2(const float &x, const float &y) :
  X(x),
  Y(y)
{
};

float &operator[] (const int &index)
{
    switch (index)
    {
    case 0:
        return X;
    case 1:
        return Y;
    }

    throw Exceptions::IndexOutOfRange();
};

float *operator & ()
{
    return &X;
};
};

template<> class TypeInfo<Vec2> : public TypeInfo_Atomic<Vec2> {}; **"error here before <"**


class Vec3 **"error here before Vec3"**
{
public:

float X, Y, Z;

Vec3() {} 
Vec3(const float &x, const float &y, const float &z) :
  X(x),
  Y(y),
  Z(z)
{
};

float &operator[] (const int &index)
{
    switch (index)
    {
    case 0:
        return X;
    case 1:
        return Y;
    case 2:
        return Z;
    }

    throw Exceptions::IndexOutOfRange();
};

float *operator & ()
{
    return &X;
};
};

template<> class TypeInfo<Vec3> : public TypeInfo_Atomic<Vec3> {}; **"error here before <"**

class Vec4 **"error here before Vec4"**
{
public:

float X, Y, Z, W;

Vec4() {} 
Vec4(const float &x, const float &y, const float &z, const float &w) :
  X(x),
  Y(y),
  Z(z),
  W(w)
{
};  

float &operator[] (const int &index)
{
    switch (index)
    {
    case 0:
        return X;
    case 1:
        return Y;
    case 2:
        return Z;
    case 3:
        return W;
    }

    throw Exceptions::IndexOutOfRange();
};

float *operator & ()
{
    return &X;
};
};

template<> class TypeInfo<Vec4> : public TypeInfo_Atomic<Vec4> {}; **"error here before <"**



class Color **"error here before Color"**
{
public:

byte R, G, B, A;

Color() {}
Color(byte r, byte g, byte b, byte a) :
  R(r),
  G(g),
  B(b),
  A(a)
{
};

byte *operator & ()
{
    return &R;
};

static const Color      Red,
                        Green,
                        Blue,
                        Yellow,
                        White,
                        Black;
};

template<> class TypeInfo<Color> : public TypeInfo_Atomic<Color> {}; **"flag here before <"**
```

there are 8 errors total. Help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: I think you meant errors or warnings instead of flags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're putting objective-c and c++ code into the same file, you need to use a .mm file extension.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html

Comment: ok, apparently I missed that one, but it worked so thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't think your module is C++.  What suffix did you give the file?

Comment: @JoshuaBell -- What is the suffix of the file where you're including it??